# Find the transformation associated with the random variable X with the following PMF:

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, transformation

Here is the question:

[image]

This is my work thus far.

[image]

Comment: I used the links you posted and entered (edited in/uploaded) images you provided.

Comment: Take $e^{\lambda}$ outside the first $\Sigma$, then group inside into $(\lambda s)^k$, then recognize the series giving a certain  exponential... The same for the second sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Taylor series for the exponential function $e^x$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ke^{sk}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\lambda e^{s}\right)^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda e^s}.
$$